# Методу передаются не все парметры

Tags: php

Опишу проблему

1. Вызываю метод

   ```
   pages::show('title', 'header', 'body', 'footer', true, 10);
   ```
2. Сам метод

   ```
   class pages {
       public static function show($title = null, $header = null, $body = true, $footer = null, $show = false, $end = 0) {
           var_dump($title); 
           var_dump($header); 
           var_dump($body); 
           var_dump($footer); 
           var_dump($show); // Этот параметр не пришел
           var_dump($end); // Этот параметр не пришел
       }
   }
   ```

Проблема в том, что методу не передались два параметра `$show` и `$end`.

Почему подобное может происходить?

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Либо ваш метод имеет логику, которую вы тут не показали и она их меняет, либо вы некорректно задаете параметры при вызове

Comment: Все отлично работает http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c14ca95a5e71e476b2776a019340527bd9b3507e